# How to manage split Web Application project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webforms

I've got a bit of an interesting project layout question for you all. I'm really not sure how to handle this, so I'm hoping someone here has a bright idea.

Basically, I have a Web Application that for the most part, is the same per customer (except the configuration files). There are certain files that are different for each and every customer (javascript, css, sql snippets), and managing all this is a bit of a pain with the setup we have now.

Currently, we have all these customised files sitting in the SVN repo and when someone comes to make changes, they first check out the core project (Web Forms Application consisting of pages, C# classes, javascript files, global styles, images, etc.) into a new working directory, then check out the customised files and export them into the working directory of the core project. Once they've finished making changes they will commit any changes that happened in the core project (bug fixes, changes/features other customers will want), and then copy back the customised files to the customised working directory and commit that. Needless to say, it's a major pain and things get missed.

My end goal is to have a single working directory for the core project (excluding any special development branches), and a customised project per customer. The developer would have a solution file that has both of these projects as part of it, they can make changes to either, and commits would go to the right repos.

Now, I could set up a multi project solution that looks like this, but functionally I have no idea what to do. How can I run the core project and have all the customised files available? How do we deploy to a testing or production server? How do we handle things like the web config that are only partially customised (e.g. connection strings)?

If anyone has worked on something like this, or has an idea on how we could set up a project like this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my working place experienced the same problem before. We ended up using branch.

Say you have 2 projects in one directory (main), and now you have another client coming in.

Simply branch this directory (main) to another directory (clientA). Now in directory clientA, you should have 2 projects.Do your daily development as usual, but just merge in the changes in core project to main branch.

```
---Main
   ----Core
   ----CustomisedSkeleton

---ClientA (branch)
   ----Core  (do merge back later)
   ----ClientACustomised (client based code, do not do any merge in)
```

One morething, since your work is web applicaton, you need update each branchs' web projects file, to make it binding to different URL on your local IIS.

Say main webapplication's url is "http://yourmachine.com/main/login.aspx", 
and you customised branch's web application url is "http://yourmachine.com/clientA/login.aspx"

Comment: This sounds like a pretty good solution to the problem. I'll show it to the higher ups and see what they say. Will update once I've done that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @djstamp how's going? Any feed back from higher level.

Comment: I'm implementing this solution on a test instance to see if it works, but so far so good. If all goes to plan I'll mark this correct by the end of the work day.